# Select2 load related data into second select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, jquery-select2

I am working with Cakephp 2.4, Select2 3.4 and Jquery 1.10.
In my app, I have a table with 3 columns -  product code, product description and product price.

I have Select2 set up so that the user can select either via product code or via product description. What I want to achieve is:

if the users selects via product code, set the product description and price and if he selects via description, set product code and price.

My data gets returned as follows:

```
[{"id":1,"text":"10001","description":"Test Product Name","unitPrice":"1.25"},    {"id":2,"text":"10002","description":"product 2","unitPrice":"5.00"},    {"id":3,"text":"10003","description":"Product 3","unitPrice":"2.74"}]
```

I am able to set the value of the second select2 box using plain jQuery:

```
$(".productCode").on('change', function (product){ 
$(".description").select2("data", {id: '1', text: 'Test'});     
});
```

What do I have to use to set the .description select2 value to the "description" value returned?

Answer (score 0):

You forget initialize the select elements. Do it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jquery select2 test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <link href="select2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="select2/select2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<input type="hidden" class="productCode" />

<select class="description" >
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() { 

    var $productCode = $(".productCode"),
        $description = $(".description"), 
        product = [{"id":1,"text":"10001","description":"Test Product Name","unitPrice":"1.25"},{"id":2,"text":"10002","description":"product 2","unitPrice":"5.00"},{"id":3,"text":"10003","description":"Product 3","unitPrice":"2.74"}];
    //should initilize two select first
    $productCode.select2({
        'placeholder' : 'input to search',
        "width" : '200px',
        "query": function(query){
            var data = {results: product};
            query.callback(data);
        }
    });
    $description.select2({
        'width' : '200px'
    });



    $productCode.on('change', function (product){ 
        $description.select2("data", {id: '1', text: 'Test'}); 
    });
});

</script> 
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use hidden inputs to back your Select2 controls, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" class="product" id="productCode" data-text="text" data-placeholder="code" />
<input type="hidden" class="product" id="description" data-text="description" data-placeholder="description" />
<input type="hidden" class="product" id="unitPrice" data-text="unitPrice" data-placeholder="unit price" />
```

And you have data like this:

```
var PRODUCTS = [
    { id: 1, text: '10001', description: 'Product 1', unitPrice: '1.25' },
    { id: 2, text: '10002', description: 'Product 2', unitPrice: '5.00' },
    { id: 3, text: '10003', description: 'Product 3', unitPrice: '2.74' }
];
```

You can populate your Select2 controls using the "data" option, like this:

```
$('.product').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.select2({
        allowClear: true,
        data: { results: PRODUCTS, text: $this.attr('data-text') }
    });
});
```

And you can use the Select2 "val" function to get and set the values, like this:

```
$('.product').change(function() {
    var selecteId = $(this).select2('val');
    $('.product').select2('val', selecteId);
});
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cwzj6Ltu/2/)